# When using C-x C-f turn off the suggestions

Tags: ido, find-file

When i do `C-x C-f` to create a new file in the directory A, if emacs finds another file in another directory (say B) with exact same name, in the mini-buffer it changes the path to the other existing file (forcing me to open the old file instead of letting me create my new file). How can i disable this annoying thing?

**Update**
It is because of the ido-vertical mode which i have in my init.el:

```
;;; ido vertical
(require 'ido-vertical-mode)
(ido-mode 1)
(ido-vertical-mode 1)
(setq ido-vertical-define-keys 'C-n-and-C-p-only)
```

Comment: This is not the standard Emacs behavior. Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). If you don't know what causes it then bisect your init file to find out. The question so far is unclear, and so risks being closed.

Comment: Folks are trying to guess what you mean - Ivy? Ido? Please clarify the question or delete it. Thx.

Comment: There's a way to turn on `ido` just for switching buffers, like this:
https://github.com/DoMiNeLa10/.emacs.d/blob/cef9e5571572195dce1497a7c2ecc4adb5589eb9/config/my-customization.el#L50

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asuming that C-x C-f is bound to ido-find-file you drop back to the non-Ido version by typing C-x C-f again or just C-f.  This will allow you to create the file you want without Ido interfence.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the default behavior of Emacs, so it's likely that you're using a package that modifies it. I'm going to guess that you're using `ido-mode`. I occasionally get annoyed by this same aspect of `ido-mode`, but I don't think there's really a fix for it. If the search is taking long enough, you can hit `C-g` to cancel it, but if it's already finished the search that will cancel the `ido-find-file` command entirely. Another work around is to hit `C-f` again before it searches, this will drop you back to the default Emacs `find-file`.

Another thing I've started doing is using `projectile-mode`. This has a command to open another file in the same project (`projectile-find-file`, bound to `C-c p f` by default) which enumerates all of the files in the project before asking you to select one. You still get `ido-mode`'s matching behavior, but since it has all the files in the project already it'll do less searching of unrelated projects. Of course, that requires that your files be in a "project" as Projectile defines it. On the other hand it treats any version-control repository as a project, which is very convenient.

And of course you have the option of disabling `ido-mode` entirely; just comment it out in your init file.

Comment: He could also be using ivy, in which case he can use the test he has input, without matching another existing entry, by using Control-Alt-j.

Comment: If it's `ido-mode` then maybe setting `ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length` to `-1` would help? I have that setting in my init file with the comment `don't jump to some other directory when I mistype a filename`.

Comment: @npostavs - i'm stuck with the same problem and it's help

Comment: Just type C-x C-f two times in a row.  This will call the non Ido version of find-file.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `ido-mode` only for buffer switching commands, here's the relevant part of the docstring for that function:

> However, if ARG arg equals ‘files’, remap only commands for files, or
>   if it equals ‘buffers’, remap only commands for buffer switching.

You can pass the symbol `buffers` to `ido-mode` to enable it only for buffer switching like this:

```
(ido-mode 'buffers)
```